# How to manually add debug type information to a GNU GAS assembly "array" symbol?

Tags: gcc, gdb, gnu-assembler, dwarf

For example, consider the following Linux freestanding `true` program with an useless `my_longs` variable for illustrative purposes:

main.S

```
.section .rodata
    my_longs: .quad 0x12, 0x34
.text
.global _start
_start:
asm_main_after_prologue:
    mov $60, %rax
    mov $0, %rdi
    syscall
```

which you can assemble and run with:

```
as -o main.o main.S
ld -o main.out main.o
gdb main.out
```

Then start the program with:

```
starti
```

Now, to see the value of `my_longs`, I have to type the annoying `(long[2])` part:

```
p/x (long[2])my_longs
```

Is there any way to tell GDB the type of `my_longs` on by adding some extra annotation to my assembly program?

When writing a C program:

main_c.c

```
long my_longs[] = {0x12, 0x34};

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with:

```
gcc -O0 -ggdb3 -save-temps -o main_c.out main_c.c
```

I can see the symbols directly with;

```
p/x my_longs
```

presumably due to the DWARF debug information GCC added.

When I had a look at the generated assembly, the only references I could find to `my_longs` were:

```
.Ltext0:
    .comm   my_longs,16,16
.Ldebug_info0:
    .long   .LASF351
    .quad   my_longs
.LASF351:
    .string "my_longs"
```

so I'm not sure where the type information is being stored.

I know that this question may come down basically to: how are types encoded in DWARF, and is it practical to manually encode that information. I intend to study DWARF a bit later on if this keeps on bothering me.

Comment: You can non-manually add debug with '--gdwarf-2'.  There are also various pseudo-ops which can encode information.  See: [CFI](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/CFI-directives.html).

Answer (score 3):

I am no DWARF expert either, but poking around with `dwarfdump` reveals enough to answer the question.

```
$ dwarfdump ./main_c.out

..  DW_TAG_variable
        DW_AT_name                  my_longs
        ...
        DW_AT_type                  <0x00000031>
```

And if we look at the type node, we'll see that it is an array (whose elements are of type described with node 0x0048 which corresponds to long int).

```
$ dwarfdump ./main_c.out  | egrep -A3 '00031'

< 1><0x00000031>    DW_TAG_array_type
                      DW_AT_type                  <0x00000048>
                      DW_AT_sibling               <0x00000041>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know `dwarfdump`. OK, from this it does not look that there is an easy way to manually encode the DWARF info :-(

Comment: Yeah, I learned about it by lurking around on SO. Manual encoding seems a bit too involved, I agree.